# Transition on navigation bar not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have this navbar but when it opens to show the content, I want it to open smoothly (With Transition) but it won't work.

Here is the example:

```css
/* Google Fonts Import Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  background: #11101d;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .logo-details i{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name{
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links{
  overflow: visible;
}
.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover{
  background: #1d1b31;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .iocn-link{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link{
  display: block
}
.sidebar .nav-links li i{
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  padding: 6px 6px 14px 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu{
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu{
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank{
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.sidebar .profile-details{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 260px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #1d1b31;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  background: none;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .profile-details img{
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 14px 0 12px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details img{
  padding: 10px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details i,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .job{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.home-section{
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 260px;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close ~ .home-section{
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}
.home-section .home-content{
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu,
.home-section .home-content .text{
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu{
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.home-section .home-content .text{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar{
    width: 78px;
  }
  .sidebar.close{
    width: 0;
  }
  .home-section{
    left: 78px;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .sidebar.close ~ .home-section{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}


body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);

}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0 88 114);
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:white;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Codify.net</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="nav">
        
    </div>


    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="logo-details">
            <i class='bx bxl-html5'></i>
            <span class="logo_name">Learn HTML5</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li>
            <div class="iocn-link">
              <a href="#">
                <i class='bx bx-chevron-right-circle' ></i>
                <span class="link_name">Let's Start!</span>
              </a>
              <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Let's Start!</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Set-up Environment</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">How HTML Works</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">HTML Structure</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
    </div>
<script>let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");});};</script>
    
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it looks and functions fine but then it needs a smooth transition once the arrow is clicked.

I tried the simple `transition: 0.5s;` but it does not seem to work.

I was hoping someone could help me out or spot my mistake.

Comment: you are already including jquery, you should use "toggle" function, that includes the duration.

Comment: You cannot add a transitions to display properties. Check out the answers on here, the main solutions around this is to use opacity and height https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property

Comment: The **display** css property can't be animated.